# Expected value and variance of random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expectation

Suppose I pick an integer independently and uniformly at random from $[1,n]$ and I repeat this experiment $t$ times.
Let $a_i$ be the number of times I pick number $i$, and let $a_{max}$ be the maximum $a_i$ of all those chosen in the experiment. Note that $t = a_1+a_2+a_3+...+a_n$

What is the expected value and variance of $\frac{a_{max}}{t}$

Comment: And... what do you think?

Comment: So far, I have only been able to relate it to an OEIS entry when $n=2$ http://oeis.org/A230137

Answer (score 0):

This experiment is a well-known experiment called balls-into-bins. As for the expectation, you can find a related question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/512455/expected-max-load-with-n-balls-in-n-bins). Also, you may find [these lecture notes](http://www.ic.unicamp.br/~celio/peer2peer/math/czumaj-balls-into-bins.pdf) useful.