# Odds of K of the Same Number Appearing on a D sided dice in N throws

Tags: probability, combinatorics, dice

Say I have a D sided dice and I toss it N times. Given a value K where K >=1 and <= N, what are the odds that K of the rolls have the same number? What are the odds that >= K of the rolls have the same number?

As a bonus follow-up, how does the above change if there is a consistent probability p that a number becomes unrollable in the future every time it is hit? That is to say, numbers become progressively less likely every time they are rolled by some consistent probability.

Comment: As a bonus, could you let us know what you have tried so far, and where you are stuck ?

Comment: What happens if $N=4$ and two of the rolls are $1$ and two are $2$.  Does this mean two have the same number?

Comment: This is is related to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/512455/expected-max-load-with-n-balls-in-n-bins