# Expected maximum occupation number for randomly distributed objects

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, summation, asymptotics, recreational-mathematics

Suppose you have $M$ distinguishable objects distributed amongst $N$ distinguishable boxes. Can you calculate the expected maximum occupation number $E_\text{max}(N,M)$? (in other words, the expected number of objects in the box with the most objects in it?)

I'm having trouble even writing this down as a sum, a convoluted way to do it (I think) would be:
$$E_\text{max}(M,N) = \frac{1}{{M+N-1}\choose{M}}\sum_{\lambda \vdash_\mathrm{ordered} n} m(\lambda) {N \choose |\lambda|} \frac{M!}{\prod_i \lambda_i!}$$
where we sum over all ordered partitions $\lambda_1 + \cdots \lambda_{|\lambda|} = n$. If this sum is hard, I'd also be interested in any asymptotics, I know in the limit that $N$ is very large and $M$ is fixed, I can write:
$$E_\text{max}(M,N) = 1 + \frac{M(M-1)}{2(N-M+1)} + O\left(\frac{1}{N^2}\right)$$
Id be interested in seeing $E_\text{max}(N,N) \sim \log(N)$ though (I don't know if this is true)

Comment: Another way to phrase this problem is in the context of 'stars and bars', sum over all configurations, weight by the largest number of stars in a single bracket

Comment: [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/512455/expected-max-load-with-n-balls-in-n-bins) asks about the case $M=N$, but the answers handle the general case, so I think this counts as a duplicate.

Comment: @MikeEarnest thanks for link! yes it’s duplicate