# Expected number of empty cells

Tags: probability, statistics

> 5 balls are distributed independently and completely at random into 5 cells. What is the expected number of empty cells?

How is this question solved using indicator variables? What I have so far is that with $A_i$ = the no. of balls in the ith cell, $E(A_i) = 1/5$. This leads to $E(A) = 1$ but it seems wrong. Can anyone explain how this is right? If it's wrong than what is wrong in my thinking?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28930/another-balls-and-bins-question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A_k = \{\text{k cells empty}\}$

Then the expected number of empty cells is 
$$
E \left(1_{A_1} + 2\;1_{A_2} + 3\;1_{A_3} + 4\;1_{A_4} \right) = P(A_1) + 2P(A_2) + 3P(A_3) + 4P(A_4).
$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: I didn't know indicator variables could be used this way. Thanks